# Issue with Form Control returning Null in group array forms Angular

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

Can anyone please assist me. I am trying to create a dynamic form that adds 2x fields (name and shares) for each division a company might have. The problem is that i am getting an error "control is null" and i have no idea why or how to fix it.

component.ts The form in question is profileStep2

````
import { Form, FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { User, Company } from '@app/_models';
import { AccountService, AlertService } from '@app/_services';
import {STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS} from '@angular/cdk/stepper';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cfar',
  templateUrl: './cfar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cfar.component.scss'],
  providers: [{
    provide: STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, useValue: {showError: true}
  }]
})
export class CfarComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;
  company: Company;
  profileStep1: FormGroup;
  profileStep2: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private accountService: AccountService
  ){ 
    this.user = this.accountService.userValue;
  }

  initDivisions() {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      share: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  addDivision(): void{
    this.formArray.push(
      this._formBuilder.group({
        name: ['', Validators.required],
        share: ['', Validators.required]
    }));
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.profileStep1 = this._formBuilder.group({
      conaolidationAproach: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this.profileStep2 = this._formBuilder.group({
      divisions: this._formBuilder.array([])
    });
  }

  log(){
    console.log(this.profileStep2.value)
  }
  get formArray(){
    return this.profileStep2.get("divisions") as FormArray;
  }
  getControls(){
    return (this.profileStep2.get('divisions') as FormArray).controls;
  }
}```

and html

```<mat-stepper #stepper>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="profileStep1" errorMessage="Consolidation Approach is required.">
      <form [formGroup]="profileStep1">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
        <h2>Consolidation Approach</h2>

        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" formControlName="conaolidationAproach" id="equityShare" value="equityShare" autocomplete="off">
        <label class="btn btn-primary" for="equityShare">Equity Share</label>

        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" formControlName="conaolidationAproach" id="finantialControl" value="finantialControl" autocomplete="off">
        <label class="btn btn-secondary" for="finantialControl">Finantial Control</label>

        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" formControlName="conaolidationAproach" id="operationalControl" value="operationalControl" autocomplete="off">
        <label class="btn btn-secondary" for="conaolidationAproach">Operational Control</label>
        
        <div>
          <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </mat-step>

    <mat-step [stepControl]="profileStep2" errorMessage=" is required.">
      <form [formGroup]="profileStep2">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Company Divisions</ng-template>
          <p>Add your companies divisions</p>
          <div formArrayName="divisions" class="row">
            <div *ngFor="let division of getControls(); let i=index">
              <div formGroupName="i">
                <label for="name">Division Name</label>
                <input type="text" formControlName="name">

                <label for="share">Share %</label>
                <input type="number" formControlName="share">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button (click)="log()">log</button>
          <button (click)="addDivision()">Add Division</button>
          <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
          <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
          <pre>{{ profileStep2.value | json }}</pre>
      </form>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
      <p>You are now done.</p>
      <div>
        
        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
        <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-stepper>
````

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it fixed. Issue was that i did not rap form group name in [],
Thanks anyway